# Open color palette on IBAction given to button

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a round rect textured button. Upon clicking that button, I want to open a color palette. I have used this code but it is not working:

```
- (IBAction)chooseColor:(id)sender
{
    NSColorPanel *colorPanel;
    colorPanel = [NSColorPanel sharedColorPanel];
    [colorPanel setColor:[sender color]];

}
```

This is a Mac application.

Comment: Why not use a standard `NSColorWell`? Clicking a button to choose a color doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: ^ What he said. Also, this is the third question of yours asking the same thing. Why are you spamming SO?

Answer (score 0):

Get that panel at anytime. Good luck!

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] orderFrontColorPanel:nil];
```